Access blocked: Authorization Error 400 : invalid scope
!gcloud auth application-default login --client-id-file client_secret.json --scopes='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/generative-language.tuning'
On the above command getting error as:
Some requested scopes were invalid. {invalid=[https://www.googleapis.com/auth/generative-language.tuning', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform]} Learn more about this error
If you are a developer of agribot, see error details.
Error 400: invalid_scope
I have done every possible solution even set the sensitive scopes in the cloud.

See Google's list of Google API scopes. I don't see a scope ending in generative-language.tuning
You can also take a look at the OAuth 2.0 playground which also has the different scopes
